# Do not match on certain word, but match if other word is in string

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I have a list which should be filtered / not matched by grep. Lets say we have a string:

`This is a keyword string, that should not match`

So in this case line should be filtered, because of containing `keyword`.

`This is another keyword string, that should match because important is now inside.`

In this case because the word `important` is contained in the string, it should match and not be filtered. Also there is a bunch of words, not just `important`, but also words like `expensive`, `attention`.

`keyword` is always before `important` in the string.

To start easy, I've tried:

`echo "This is a keyword string, that should not match" | grep -i --invert 'keyword'`
This works so far, output is empty.

Then to play around with negative look behind, I've tried

`echo "This is a keyword string, that should not match" | grep -i --invert 'keyword.*?(?!important)'`
But that matches. As soon as `.*?` is introduced, it will match:

```
echo "This is a keyword string, that should not match" | grep -i --invert 'keyword.*?'
This is a keyword string, that should not match
```

Hope this is possible via grep only. Otherwise some lines of bash code are also acceptable.

Update unsing `-P` option:
`echo "This is a keyword string, that should not match, but now important is included" | grep -i --invert -P 'keyword.*?(?!important).*?'` returns an empty string

Comment: If input is `This is a keyword string but it is inexpensive` then should this be filtered out or not?

Comment: @Hannes : Simple regular expressions do not support look-behind. You could try `-P` to play with such features.

Comment: When you say "filtered" do you mean "printed" or "deleted"? Do these "bunch of words" always come after "keyword" on each line or could they come before it? Please [edit] your question to simply show a block of 4 or 5 lines of input that covers your requirements and the associated output given that input to help clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably have better luck with awk.

```
awk '/keyword/ && !/attention|expensive|important/ { next } 1'
```

If you have GNU grep, I guess something like this would also work:

```
grep -P -v 'keyword(?!.*(attention|expensive|important))'
```